# Google Play Developer Console: switch between accounts

Tags: google-play-store

Is there a way to switch between Google accounts when I'm in the Play Store Developer Console?

It is extremely frustrating when the first Google account I have logged into is not the one I use for the Play Store - I have to log out of all the accounts first and then log back in remembering the right sequence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this at the moment.

My workaround for such issues is to use another browser for the second account, or to use a different user account in Google Chrome.

Comment: I'll accept this answer for now. It would be great if you could refer to an official source, though.

Comment: When will google fix this issue!?, simply unacceptable, especially since it works for all their other services

Answer (score 3):

While you cannot switch between Google accounts, you can switch between multiple developer accounts that one Google account has access to (As shown in the screenshot provided by Philippe Cohen). You can grant access to a developer account by going to Settings > Users & permissions.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why I didn't think of it. At the same time, it's 2019, and all this is the only Google property I'm aware of that doesn't support account switching.

Comment: I like this solution best

Answer (score 3):

[As of today](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/06/introducing-new-google-play-console-beta.html), yes, you can!

The [new generation Play Console](https://play.google.com/console) supports user switching using the familiar `/u/NUMBER` url structure. Just use the account switcher on the top right or urls like https://play.google.com/console/u/1, https://play.google.com/console/u/2, etc.

Answer (score -1):

When you click in your account avatar on the top right corner of the Google Play Console, you will have a drop down enabling you to switch to any of your accounts. See below

[image]